# SQL select IDs that is not on another table, unless that register has certain column data

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT id FROM order o 
INNER JOIN order_payment p ON p.parent_id=o.entity_id 
WHERE o.state='new' 
AND o.created_at BETWEEN '2013-05-14' 
AND '2013-10-11 00:19:09' 
AND p.method IN ('paymethod_a', 'paymethod_b', 'paymethod_c') 
--AND o.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM order o 
--INNER JOIN payment_method pm ON pm.order_id=o.id 
--WHERE o.created_at BETWEEN '2013-05-14' AND '2013-10-11 00:19:09')**
```

In the commented section, I don't want to get any of the id's which matches on the table payment_method.order_id (foreign key) too. 
But now, a system update changed things: now I want to get the same results at the commented area, PLUS: if a payment_method register has a 'status=0' column, I have to get that id too, nevermind if the order.id is on payment_method.order_id (foreign key).

I suck at SQL, can anyone help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, NOT IN (subselect query) are poor on performance.  Instead, it is much better to do a LEFT-JOIN and accept the record if the other table is NULL (indicating NOT there).  This also helps your condition if the OTHER special condition MAY exist which you want to include.  Something like:

```
SELECT 
      o.id 
   FROM 
      order o 
         JOIN order_payment op 
            ON o.entity_id = op.parent_id
           AND op.method in ('paymethod_a', 'paymethod_b', 'paymethod_c') 
         LEFT JOIN payment_method pm
            on o.id = pm.order_id
   where
          o.state='new' 
      AND o.created_at BETWEEN '2013-05-14' AND '2013-10-11 00:19:09' 
      AND ( pm.order_id IS NULL
           OR pm.status = 0 )
```

Comment: Seems that you got it. "pm.order_id IS NULL" is what I wanted. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

take into consideration that you want to join 3 different table and include with status 0

```
SELECT id FROM order o 
INNER JOIN order_payment p ON p.parent_id=o.entity_id 
INNER JOIN payment_method t3 ON t3.order_ID = o.orderID
WHERE o.state='new' 
AND o.created_at BETWEEN '2013-05-14' 
AND '2013-10-11 00:19:09' 
--query modified,if there are only one parameters,Function 'IN' is not supported
AND p.method = 'payment_method'

--you never exclude status = 0 in payment_method table, so nothing is needed to do at all
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question. I have lots of payment methods, for the IN function. I need to get the results that is not on payment_method table PLUS the results that, if are in that table, MUST have status = 0.